# backbone.js in Salesforce1

Tags: javascript, rest-api, salesforce1-app, mobilesdk, html5

I am starting to build some mobile samples in Salesforce1 using backbone.js
I came across two js libraries -

1. Backbone.Force 
   https://github.com/pwalczyszyn/Backbone.Force
   this extends backbone.js and enables force.com connectivity
2. force.entity.js
   https://github.com/developerforce/MobilePack-BackboneJS
   this is included in the mobilepack for backbone.js

Are both these libraries trying to achieve same thing ?
do they allow to create model and fetch the model contents directly from Salesforce using REST APIs ?

has anyone used any of these before ?

Comment: to me both looks to achieve similar functionality and they both use the same forcetk library internally ..